# Creating a clone() method that casts one class to another

Tags: java, class, clone

We are given the requirements to write a `clone()` method so that executing the following additional code:

```
Circuit c = (Circuit) p2.clone();
System.out.println( c + " = " + c.getResistance());
```

Would yield this result:

`( ( ( ( 2.0 + 3.0 ) || 4.0) + 1.0 ) || 8.0) = 2.297029702970297`

For brevity sake, I'm not going to post all the methods and constructors used (there's a lot, unfortunately, so if I want to fulfill SSCCE question-asking standards, posting them all would definitely not be short and concise), but I'll use this main method to demonstrate to you what `p2` is:

```
SeriesCircuit s1 = new SeriesCircuit(new Circuit(2.0), new Circuit(3.0));
ParallelCircuit p1 = new ParallelCircuit(s1, new Circuit(4.0));
SeriesCircuit s2 = new SeriesCircuit(p1, new Circuit(1.0));
ParallelCircuit p2 = new ParallelCircuit(s2, new Circuit(8.0));
```

Using this:

```
System.out.println(p2 + " = " + p2.getResistance());
```

Would also print:

`( ( ( ( 2.0 + 3.0 ) || 4.0) + 1.0 ) || 8.0) = 2.297029702970297`

P.S. I have done all the parts leading up to the `.clone()` requirement.

The question asked in the assignment requires us to to convert a `SeriesCircuit`/`ParallelCircuit`/`Circuit` to `SeriesCircuit`/`ParallelCircuit`/`Circuit` using the `.clone()` method.

Each `Parallel` or `Circuit` or `Series` class contains their own (unique) private variables that are outputted through either `.getResistance()` (which returns a double), or `.toString()`, which gets a formatted string not unlike what you see above.

Could someone explain to me how to convert a class with its own private variables to another class? I am not asking for completed code, and while I have an inkling to that concept, I have no idea how to execute it.

Comment: What does your class inheritance map look like?

Comment: How could I show you my class inheritance map, @duncan? I am currently using Eclipse.

Comment: You could just describe it, or draw it with ascii-art if you like.  I actually meant that as a bit of a nudge, since that's what this question is ultimately about.

Comment: The `clone()` method does not convert one type to another, rather it makes a copy of the object.  I presume that `SeriesCircuit` and `ParallelCircuit` are subclasses of `Circuit` (which is why @duncan asked for your class inheritance map) - The general approach is to have all of your classes implement the `Clonable` interface and the `clone` method.  This method copies the properties of itself and calls the `clone` method of its superclass.  Through polymorphism you can execute `Circuit c = (Circuit) p2.clone();` even though p2 is a `ParallelCircuit`

Comment: Ah, so there is a `Clonable` interface that can be used. @Paulw11, could you give me a demonstration in the answers section, on how this could be used? @duncan - yes, the `SeriesCircuit` and `ParallelCircuit` are subclasses of `Circuit`, though they don't explicitly inherit anything from each other (i.e. using `superclass` or using the `super()` constructor).. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You need your classes to implement the `Cloneable` interface.  You can then override the `clone()` method.  This method obtains a new object by calling `super.clone()` and then copies the data values either by assignment for intrinsics (and immutables) or cloning for objects.  As an example for a class Y that inherits from class X -

```
public class X implements Cloneable {

   private int someVariable;

   public X clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
   {
       X newX=super.clone();
       newX.someVariable=this.someVariable;
       return newX
   }

public class Y extends X implements Cloneable {

   private Z someClassVariable;
   private float myVariable;

   public Y clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
   {
       Y newY=super.clone();
       newY.someClassVariable=this.someClassVariable.clone();
       newY.myVariable = this.myVariable;

       return newY;
   }


   public class Z implements Cloneable {

   private int someOtherVariable;

   public Z clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
   {
       Z newZ=super.clone();
       newX.someOtherVariable=this.someVariable;
       return newZ
   }
```

Comment: So my `Circuit` class would extend upon my `Series` or `Parallel` class and also implement the `Cloneable` interface?

Comment: No, your `Circuit` class is the superclass (class X in my example), but yes, all of the classes need to implement clone able - even classes that are not in the inheritance path, such as class Z, if they need to be cloned.  One of the downsides of `clone()` is that it can be tricky if you use other classes that don't implement `Cloneable`

Comment: Could we open a chat room? I have some questions. My `Series` and `Parallel` classes do not explicitly inherit anything from my `Circuit ` class, though because they are public classes, doing what I do in my `main` method as shown above still makes everything work.

Comment: I am in the Java chat room now